# QML Image Masking

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have been working on a project where I need to apply image masking that applies an effect like this:

Pic1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zI2x.jpg

Pic2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7IVX.jpg

Mask frame: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3syEm.jpg

Desired effect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2kO5.jpg

I got it to work by using OpacityMask however to do that I had to use some photoshop and edit my mask frame image. I need to apply this affect to multiple mask frames with different shapes therefore using photoshop to edit all of them seem troublesome. Moreover, the inside of the mask frame images arent all transparent either.

Is there any ideas you can give me to solve this issue without using any pre photoshoping each mask frame images. I tried to look into ShaderEffect but I could not really understand how I should use it for my purpose. Moreover I searched for a OpacityMask like effect but working only on part of the mask image which has a specific color/specific shaped area. However, I could not find any.

Comment: Why did you even need Photoshop, I didn't understand.
In any case, could you perhaps be more specific about the shape you are referring to? a circle? triangle? or just a rectangle? Is the center of your frame transparent? If not, have you tried using [Blend](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-blend.html)?

Comment: @SMR as I have said the center of the frame is not transparent. And each mask I have has different shape.  Like one is oval, the other is rectangle etc. Their only similar quality is that their center are the same colour and their frame are the same colour. I will look into blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShaderEffect` appears to be the only option, considering what you said in the comments that the frame shape could be anything.
The code examples below show how to solve your issue with `ShaderEffect`.

#### QML code

The only property on the **QML** side is the `rect`, which defines the `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` of the **frame**, which are scaled down to between `0` and `1`.

```
Image { id: img;  visible: false; source: "2.jpg" }
Image { id: frme; visible: false; source: "3.jpg" }
Image { id: back; visible: false; source: "1.jpg" }

ShaderEffect {
    width: img.sourceSize.width / 3.5
    height: img.sourceSize.height / 3.5
    property var back: back
    property var image: img
    property var frame: frme

    property vector4d rect: Qt.vector4d(width/2-50, height/2-60, 100, 120);
    readonly property vector4d frect: Qt.vector4d(rect.x/width,rect.y/height,
                                                  rect.z/width,rect.w/height);
    fragmentShader: "qrc:/shader.glsl"
}
```

#### `shader.glsl`

I discovered that the **saturation** inside the image is very different from other areas after using a color picker in different points of the frame image.

So, in order to decide where to mask in the image, I used **saturation**.

```c
uniform highp sampler2D back;
uniform highp sampler2D image;
uniform highp sampler2D frame;
varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
uniform highp vec4 frect;
uniform highp float qt_Opacity;

// From https://gist.github.com/983/e170a24ae8eba2cd174f
vec3 rgb2hsv(vec3 c) {
    vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);
    vec4 p = mix(vec4(c.bg, K.wz), vec4(c.gb, K.xy), step(c.b, c.g));
    vec4 q = mix(vec4(p.xyw, c.r), vec4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));
    float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);
    float e = 1.0e-10;
    return vec3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);
}

void main() {
    vec2 u = qt_TexCoord0;
    vec2 frameCoord = (u - frect.xy) / frect.zw ;

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(back, u);

    if(frameCoord.x>0. && frameCoord.y>0. && frameCoord.x<1. && frameCoord.y<1.) {
        vec4 mask = texture2D(frame, frameCoord);
        vec3 hsv = rgb2hsv(mask.xyz);

        gl_FragColor = mask;
        // Check that the saturation is between 0 and 0.2.
        if(abs(hsv.y - 0.1) < 0.1) {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(image, u);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Note

You can also change the last line of code if you want the frame's shadow to cover your image.

```c
gl_FragColor = mix(texture2D(image, u), mask, 1. - hsv.z);
```

#### Result

|  |
| --- |
| [image] |

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the geometry of your picture frame is just a rectangle, we can just create a rectangular mask aligned within your picture frame. I worked out that your picture frame was 410x500 pixels and decided to shrink it to 50% i.e. 205x250 pixels. At that scale, I worked out that your picture frame had a border size of about 18 pixels. So I created an inner rectangle based on those dimensions and used that rectangle for the `OpacityMask` `maskSource`:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Page {
    Image {
        id: pic1
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zI2x.jpg"
    }

    Image {
        id: pic2
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: false
        source: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7IVX.jpg"
    }

    Image {
        id: rawMask
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 205
        height: 250
        source: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/3syEm.jpg"
    }

    Item {
        id: mask
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle {
            id: borderMask
            x: rawMask.x + 18
            y: rawMask.y + 18
            width: rawMask.width - 36
            height: rawMask.height - 36
            color: "white"
        }
    }

    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: pic2
        maskSource: mask
    }
}
```

[image]